# How can I clear previous value of <input> text by selenium in C#.Net?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, input, do-while

I want to order several times on a specific website by selenium (do-while), but the website does not clear value of  text after clicking on order button. I want to clear value of  text after click on button by selenium in C#.Net so that orders done repeatedly. My code is:

```
do{     
                /// set txtPrice                
                BuyActions.MoveToElement(cDriver.FindElementByCssSelector("#send_order_txtPrice"));
                BuyActions.Click();                
                BuyActions.SendKeys(BuyPrice);

                /// set txtCount            
                BuyActions.MoveToElement(cDriver.FindElementByCssSelector("#send_order_txtCount"));
                BuyActions.Click();                
                BuyActions.SendKeys(BuyCount);

                /// click btnBuy            
               BuyActions.MoveToElement(cDriver.FindElementByCssSelector("#send_order_btnSendOrder"));
                BuyActions.Click();
                BuyActions.Build().Perform();
} while (stop == 0);
```

Comment: In Selenium you can use `.Clear()` to remove the text. You will just need to locate the textbox like so:  

`var textfield = chromeDriver.FindElementByName("Name");`
`texfield.Clear();`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code - It should work.

```
BuyActions.MoveToElement(cDriver.FindElementByCssSelector("#send_order_txtPrice"));
BuyActions.Clear();
BuyActions.Click();                
BuyActions.SendKeys(BuyPrice);
```